# Concatenating strings faster than appending to lists

Tags: python, string, performance, list, python-3.x

I am trying to isolate specific items in a list (e.g. `[0, 1, 1]` will return `[0, 1]`). I managed to get through this, but I noticed something strange.

When I tried to append to list it ran about 7 times slower then when I was concatenating strings and then splitting it.

This is my code:

```
import time
start = time.time()

first = [x for x in range(99999) if x % 2 == 0]
second = [x for x in range(99999) if x % 4 == 0]

values = first + second

distinct_string = ""

for i in values:
    if not str(i) in distinct_string:
        distinct_string += str(i) + " "

print(distinct_string.split())

print(" --- %s sec --- " % (start - time.time()))
```

**This result end in about 5 seconds...** Now for the lists:

```
import time
start = time.time()

first = [x for x in range(99999) if x % 2 == 0]
second = [x for x in range(99999) if x % 4 == 0]

values = first + second

distinct_list = []

for i in values:
    if not i in distinct_list:
        distinct_list.append(i)

print(distinct_list)

print(" --- %s sec --- " % (start - time.time()))
```

**Runs at around 40 seconds.**

What makes string faster even though I am converting a lot of values to strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that it's generally better to use `timeit` to compare functions, which runs the same thing multiple times to get average performance, and to factor out repeated code to focus on the performance that matters. Here's my test script:

```
first = [x for x in range(999) if x % 2 == 0]
second = [x for x in range(999) if x % 4 == 0]

values = first + second

def str_method(values):
    distinct_string = ""
    for i in values:
        if not str(i) in distinct_string:
            distinct_string += str(i) + " "
    return [int(s) for s in distinct_string.split()]

def list_method(values):
    distinct_list = []
    for i in values:
        if not i in distinct_list:
            distinct_list.append(i)
    return distinct_list

def set_method(values):
    seen = set()
    return [val for val in values if val not in seen and seen.add(val) is None]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert str_method(values) == list_method(values) == set_method(values)
    import timeit
    funcs = [func.__name__ for func in (str_method, list_method, set_method)]
    setup = 'from __main__ import {}, values'.format(', '.join(funcs))
    for func in funcs:
        print(func)
        print(timeit.timeit(
            '{}(values)'.format(func),
            setup=setup,
            number=1000
        ))
```

I've added int conversion to make sure that the functions return the same thing, and get the following results:

```
str_method
1.1685157899992191
list_method
2.6124089090008056
set_method
0.09523714500392089
```

Note that it is not true that searching in a list is faster than searching in a string if you have to convert the input:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('1 in l', setup='l = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]')
0.15300405000016326
>>> timeit.timeit('str(1) in s', setup='s = "9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1"')
0.23205067300295923
```

Repeated `append`ing to a list is not very efficient, as it means frequent resizing of the underlying object - the list comprehension, as shown in the `set` version, is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

searching in strings:

if not str(i) in distinct_string:

is much faster

then searching in lists

if not i in distinct_list:

```
here are lprofile lines for string search in OP code

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time      Line Contents 


    17     75000     80366013   1071.5     92.7       if not str(i) in distinct_string:
    18     50000      2473212     49.5      2.9                  distinct_string += str(i) + " "

and for list search in OP code

   39     75000    769795432  10263.9     99.1          if not i in distinct_list:
   40     50000      2813804     56.3      0.4              distinct_list.append(i)
```

Comment: What do you think about the string implementation of the problem? Is there anything I could have done better? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you want to remove specific items from the list? what kind of list you have? and what is a rule for  removing items?

Comment: I just have a list of values and I have to remove duplicates. I made these big lists just to measure performance difference.

Comment: @user2820892 you will likely find a `set` the best way to approach this.

Comment: @user2820892 just use yourList = list(set(yourList)) that will remove duplicates

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a flaw of logic that makes the string method seemingly much faster.
When matching substrings in a long string, the `in` operator will return prematurely at the first *substring* containing the search item. To prove this, I let the loop run backwards from the highest values down to the smallest, and it returned only 50% of the values of the original loop (I checked the length of the result only). If the matching was exact there should be no difference whether you check the sequence from the start or from the end. I conclude that the string method short-cuts a lot of comparisons by matching near the start of the long string. The particular choice of duplicates is unfortunately masking this.

In a second test, I let the string method search for `" " + str(i) + " "` to eliminate substring matches. Now it will run only about 2x faster than the list method (but still, faster).

@jonrsharpe: Regarding the set_method I cannot see why one would touch all set elements one by one and not in one `set` statement like this:

```
def set_method(values):
    return list(set(values))
```

This produces exactly the same output and runs about 2.5x faster on my PC.

Comment: Yes you are correct, set is faster... Thought I didn't know about that before... So I came up with lists. That was really slow for those longer test cases (I always like to test the worst case scenario). Then I switched logic and tried with strings. This time much faster. So I was just wandering... And I learned that there actually is a simpler way (set method).

Comment: Do you agree that the string_method incorrectly matches substrings, which in your case happens unnoticed? With different values this might return incorrect results.

Comment: I couldn't imagine the case... In my head it goes like this: find item in string turn boolean around (not) and add if true (not found in string) add it to string. But if you can please provide me with any that would return incorrect results. But... It's not that much important any more (besides me learning new things) because I will probably use set() from now on...

Comment: Sorry, last comment on this as I don't want to drag it out...Say all even numbers have been added and now you add multiples of 4: "4" will match the (even) "4" or "14" or "24", "42",...so the time to find the match not only depends on the position of the exact match but on the number of other values as well which might be a partial match. This is why reversing the search direction yields different results (which it shouldn't).